# Physical applications of the mathematical curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I was studying multivariable calculus last semester and had one of the topics talking about a [curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature), but we had no applications on it. So how does it help in physics?

E.g. curvature of curve: $k=|T(t)|/|r'(t)|.$

Comment: You do realize that we are not all in your calculus course and familiar with your specific notation, right? Please define your question better

Comment: The Wikipedia link says: _This quantity is common in physics and engineering; for example, in the equations of bending in beams, the 1D vibration of a tense string, approximations to the fluid flow around surfaces (in aeronautics), and the free surface boundary conditions in ocean waves._ That, for plane curves. If you ask about the curvature of manifolds, you have General Relativity.